# Fortify Software Security Center Database (HA) Issue

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, alwayson

We have deployed Fortify Software Security Center in an environment with configured MSSQL ssc_db. How would I configure the High Availability Database configuration in Fortify SSC if possible? Otherwise, if I can enable the option Always On Availability Group option in MSSQL, what configuration would I need to change in Fortify SSC?